# Vue Typescript component library - Working with Webpack and SASS

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, webpack, vue-cli

I'm currently in the process of building a Vue UI component library for a company and in this process, I'm using webpack as the default bundler. I want to build the whole project into an npm package that then can be distributed via a private git package repository.
The package distribution is up and running, but I can't seem to get components exported in the right way so it's possible to use in another project.

Versions for different tools used:

**npm: 6.14.4**

**node: 12.17.0**

**yarn: 1.22.0**

**@vue/cli: 4.4.1**

**tsc: 3.9.5**

Project structure is as follows:

```
public
src
 - assets
  | - css
  |  | - tailwind.css
  | - fonts
  |  | - stylesheet.css
 - component
  | - LbButton
  |  | - LbButton.vue
  |  | - index.ts
  | - Lbtag
  |  | - LbTag.vue
  |  | - index.ts
  | - ...
 - theme
  | - index.ts
  | - Theme.ts
 - typedefs
  | - types.ts
  | - events.ts
  | - model.ts
  | - states.ts
 - views
  | - Home.vue
 - App.vue
 - index.ts
 - main.ts
 - plugin.ts
 - shims-vue.d.ts
vue.config.js
tailwind.config.js
tsconfig.json
postcss.config.js
babel.config.js
package.json
```

The current setup contains the following configurations:

**package.json**

```
  ...
  "main": "./dist/@livebackend/ui.common.js",
  ...
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build --target lib --name @livebackend/ui src/index.ts ",
    "test:unit": "vue-cli-service test:unit"
  },
  "files": [
    "dist/*",
    "src/*",
    "public/*",
    "*.json",
    "*.vue",
    "*.ts",
    "*.js"
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "@kazupon/vue-i18n-loader": "^0.5.0",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.152",
    "@types/vue-i18n": "^7.0.0",
    "@types/vue-select": "^2.5.0",
    "core-js": "^3.6.4",
    "date-fns": "^2.14.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.15",
    "v-calendar": "^1.0.6",
    "vue": "^2.6.11",
    "vue-class-component": "^7.2.3",
    "vue-i18n": "^8.18.1",
    "vue-infinite-loading": "^2.4.5",
    "vue-property-decorator": "^8.4.1",
    "vue-select": "^3.10.3",
    "vuex": "^3.1.3",
    "vuex-class": "^0.3.2"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "@vue/composition-api": "^0.6.7"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/chai": "^4.2.11",
    "@types/mocha": "^5.2.4",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.3.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-typescript": "~4.3.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-unit-mocha": "~4.3.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-vuex": "~4.3.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~4.3.0",
    "@vue/composition-api": "^0.6.7",
    "@vue/test-utils": "1.0.0-beta.31",
    "chai": "^4.1.2",
    "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
    "sass": "^1.26.5",
    "sass-loader": "^8.0.2",
    "style-loader": "^1.2.1",
    "tailwindcss": "1.4.6",
    "ts-loader": "^7.0.5",
    "typescript": "~3.9.5",
    "vue-style-loader": "^4.1.2",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.11"
  },
  "version": "0.4.8"
}
```

**tsconfig**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "esnext",
    "module": "esnext",
    "strict": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "types": [
      "webpack-env"
    ],
    "paths": {
      "@/*": [
        "src/*"
      ]
    },
    "lib": [
      "esnext",
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "scripthost"
    ]
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts",
    "src/**/*.vue"
  ],
  "files": [
    "src/vue-shims.d.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

**vue.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  publicPath: "./src",
  devServer: {
    proxy: "http://localhost:3000"
  },
  chainWebpack: config => {
    config.plugins.delete("optimize-css");
  },
  configureWebpack: {
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          resourceQuery: /blockType=i18n/,
          type: "javascript/auto",
          loader: "@kazupon/vue-i18n-loader"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
};
```

**tailwind.config.js**

```
const settings = {
  theme: {},
  variants: {},
  plugins: []
};

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
  settings.purge = ["./src/**/*.html", "./src/**/*.vue", "./src/**/*.jsx"];
}

module.exports = settings;
```

**src/index.ts**

```
export { default as Theme } from "./theme";
export { default as LbButton } from "./components/lbButton";
export { default as LbInputField } from "./components/lbInputField";
export { default as LbIconButton } from "./components/lbIconButton";
export { default as LbTag } from "./components/lbTag";
export { default as LbCard } from "./components/lbCard";
export { default as LbFB } from "./components/lbFB";
export { default as LbDatePicker } from "./components/lbDatePicker";
export { default as LbRadio } from "./components/lbRadio";
export { default as LbLoading } from "./components/lbLoading";
export { default as LbSlider } from "./components/lbSlider";
export { default as LbSwitch } from "./components/lbSwitch";
export { default as LbTable } from "./components/lbTable";
import plugin from "./plugin";
export default plugin;
```

**main.ts**

```
import Vue from "vue";
import VueI18n from "vue-i18n";
import vSelect from "vue-select";
import VCalendar from "v-calendar";
import "@/assets/css/tailwind.css";
import "@/assets/fonts/stylesheet.css";
import "vue-select/dist/vue-select.css";
import InfiniteLoading from "vue-infinite-loading";

import App from "./App.vue";
import messages from "./tranlations";

Vue.config.productionTip = false;

Vue.component("v-select", vSelect);
Vue.use(VCalendar, {
  componentPrefix: "v" 
});
Vue.use(VueI18n);
Vue.use(InfiniteLoading);

const i18n = new VueI18n({
  locale: "en",
  messages
});

new Vue({
  i18n,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount("#app");
```

If I need to post more files, please don't hesitate to ask.
When i bundle all of this up and include it in a project like `import { LbButton } from "@livebackend/ui"`  I get an error that tells me that vue can't find type declarations or module. When i then try to import it from `"@livebackend/ui/src"` I get another error that tells me vue can't figure out what "@" means. I use "@" to find relative modules within the project.

Is there anyone that have had these problems before ?

Answer (score 2):

I was also searching for same info and found this question, I have tried many repos and blogs/tutorials and https://github.com/team-innovation/vue-sfc-rollup was the best solution I have found so far, but I will update this answer once I will be using it longer. I have just started yesterday and I am putting features there one by one to see whether I hit something.

EDIT: 2.NOV.2020

I had to put

```
configureWebpack: {
  resolve: {
      alias: {
        vue: path.resolve("./node_modules/vue")
      }
    }
}
```

to fix issue `[Vue warn]: $listeners is read-only.`

ref: https://github.com/team-innovation/vue-sfc-rollup/issues/26